# applying searchPipe in nested element

Tags: angular, search, pipe

I have the following pipe which is not working properly in some situation like in below
Stackblitz i have added my whole code sample please help me figure out solution.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gnfkg9?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're assigning the wrong student object in the 2nd case... look closely

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Comment: @AviadP i know what you mean but in my code i have used it differently but I have other solution with lbsn's solution. Thank you for help.

Comment: @R.Richards Thank you will follow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AppComponent `query` is starting as `undefined`, so the pipe is receiving `filterText` param as `undefined`. As a consequence this line raises an exception:

```
filterText = filterText.toLowerCase();
```

You need to handle that case in your pipe implementation, for example by adding:

```
if (!filterText ) {
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign blank string to query as initially it is undefined.

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  query = '';   // Assign blank string here.
  students: any;

  constructor(private studentService: StudentsService) {
    this.students = this.studentService.students;
  }
}
```